# How to create a node with mulitple field-collection items?

Tags: 7, entities

I've a content type having filed collection item (3 fields of 5 sets). Created a custom module form, when user submits that form, it should create a node with all 5 set field collection items.

So far tried the following code. it's working for 1st set but not for all.

```
$values = array(
  'type' => 'ct_machine_name', // Content Type machine name
  'uid' => $uid,
  'status' => 1,
  'promote' => 0,
  'title' => 'xxxx',
);
$entity = entity_create('node', $values);
$ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);
$ewrapper->save();
$node = node_load($entity->nid);

$fc_val= entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'field_fc_mcnename'));
// Attach to the node
$fc_val->setHostEntity('node', $node);
$fc_val->field_field1[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $val1;
$fc_val->field_field2[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $val2;
$fc_val->field_field3[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $val3;

// Save field-collection item.
$fc_val->save();
```

The above code working. But I need to loop through it and save all field collection items in an user submitted order.

I tired as follows, but doesn't work. (example)

```
for ($i=0; $i<=4; $i++) {
$fc_val->field_field1[LANGUAGE_NONE][$i]['value'] = $val1;
$fc_val->field_field2[LANGUAGE_NONE][$i]['value'] = $val2;
$fc_val->field_field3[LANGUAGE_NONE][$i]['value'] = $val3;
}
$fc_val->save();
```

Also tried

```
for ($i=0; $i<=4; $i++) {
$fc_val->field_field1[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $val1;
$fc_val->field_field2[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $val2;
$fc_val->field_field3[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $val3;
$fc_val->save();
}
```

Any inputs or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check this out [Create node programatically with nested fieldcollection item Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2015-01-08/create-node-programatically-with#comment-10066624) It may help you.

Comment: Hey @berramou sorry for not mentioned that URL in my question. Yes I've tried but no luck.

Comment: Hey Okay and this one with Entity meta data wrapper [Example using field collections](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers)   Example using field collections Section?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
Example for field1 and repeat it with other fields.

```
$entity_fc_val = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $fc_val);
$entity_fc_val->field_field1->set(array('value' => $val1));
```